# Using math.floor to round down to a specific decimal point

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Given the string `a="1.351"`, how do I round down to 2 decimal points? I tried:

```
a = "1.351"
b = "%0.2f" % float(a)
c = math.floor(float(b))  
print c  # gives me an output of 1.0
```

Ideally I would like an output of `1.30`.

Comment: Why do you think `1.30` is the correct output? Have you tried using `round`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant to say the expected output was:

```
1.35
```

Then you can try the following:

```
a = 1.351
print math.floor(a*100)/100
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways. For example:

```
>>> a = "1.351"
>>> b = float(a)
>>> print("%.2f" % (b - b % 0.01))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
a = "1.351"
float(int(float('{:.2f}'.format(float(a)))*10))/10
```

Output :

1.3

for b= b="1254.25465"

output = `1254.2`